# CSS aplicando o before em todos os elementos

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Olá, tenho o seguinte código:
`html`

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./teste.css">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7a5258e51f.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="estrelas">
        <input type="radio" id="cm_star-empty" name="fb" value="" disabled />
        <label for="cm_star-1"><i class="fa"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="cm_star-1" name="fb" value="1" disabled />
        <label for="cm_star-2"><i class="fa"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="cm_star-2" name="fb" value="2" checked disabled />
        <label for="cm_star-3"><i class="fa"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="cm_star-3" name="fb" value="3" disabled />
        <label for="cm_star-4"><i class="fa"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="cm_star-4" name="fb" value="4" disabled />
        <label for="cm_star-5"><i class="fa"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="cm_star-5" name="fb" value="5" disabled />
    </div>

    <div class="estrelas">
        <input type="radio" id="cm_star-empty" name="fb" value="" disabled />
        <label for="cm_star-1"><i class="fa"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="cm_star-1" name="fb" value="1" checked disabled />
        <label for="cm_star-2"><i class="fa"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="cm_star-2" name="fb" value="2" disabled />
        <label for="cm_star-3"><i class="fa"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="cm_star-3" name="fb" value="3" disabled />
        <label for="cm_star-4"><i class="fa"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="cm_star-4" name="fb" value="4" disabled />
        <label for="cm_star-5"><i class="fa"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" id="cm_star-5" name="fb" value="5" disabled />
    </div>

</body>
```

`css`

```
.estrelas input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.estrelas label i.fa {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.estrelas label i.fa:before {
    content: "\f005"; /* F089*/
    color: #fc0;
}

.estrelas input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label i.fa:before {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

Esse código gera um "rating", com as estrelinhas de 1 a 5. O problema é que quando eu coloco mais de um componente (a classe "estrelas"), ele aplica no segundo em diante como se fosse 5 estrelas. Pelo que pesquisei é por conta que "o :before não suporta diversos conteúdos simultaneamente".

Pelo código, o que eu gostaria é que no primeiro apenas 2 estrelas estivessem sendo exibidas, e no segundo uma estrela. Como eu poderia consertar isso utilizando apenas HTML/CSS/JS?